# Give Priority to Account Over Alias in Postfix Virtual

Tags: linux, postfix

I am trying to have email directed to an account named "support" using Postfix `virtual_alias_maps` but there is an alias in `/etc/aliases` for support which is getting priority. My question is, can I make it so that an entry in `/etc/postfix/virtual` will give priority to a matching account before looking for aliases? Or any other advice which might help with this situation. Currently I have just commented out the support entry in the aliases file. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you messing with `virtual_alias_domains` ? Should probably be the `virtual_alias_maps` instead, you can have multiple values, separate wtih a comma.  What I'm not sure on is if they are searched in order provided and if a search is stopped once a result is found.

Comment: Sorry, I mean virtual_alias_maps, I'm only using virtual_alias_domains to specify the domains they can apply to.

Comment: Glad I guessed right :)  In any case, you can still use two values, comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't give an address priority but you can disable the entry in `/etc/aliases`. Presumably your server handles mail for your domain using `local` as well as with virtual maps. The convention is to allow the virtual mapping to handle addresses found in `aliases` in this case. To remove an entry from `aliases` comment it out and run

```
postalias
```

to rebuild the database.